# How to load WP functions?

Tags: php

I have a `mymail.php` script which sends a email (I managed to do it using `require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php' );`.) and outputs a plain text string (Such as "Email is sent successfully.")

I want to use the functions defined in WP in this my script. The particular function I want to call is `get_option()` in order to retrieve the email user of the site owner. Which file to import for the particular `get_option()` function and which to import the entire WP core (like the context available for theme's .php files?

Comment: Where does this `mymail.php` file live, and how is it executed? Is it part of a Plugin or Theme, or is it a stand-alone file executed outside of WordPress?

Comment: @Chip Bennett: <code>mymail.php</code> is located in the same dir where <code>style.css</code> and <code>functions.php</code> of the custom theme I am developing is located. It is executed from a .js file when a user clicks a submit button in a form of our theme. <code>mymail.php</code> is executed outside of WordPress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root problem here is that you should never make direct requests to PHP files in a theme or plugins from the browser. It is extreme bad practice, fragile, and open to lots of security issues.

To get this working as is you would need to bootstrap WordPress by putting something similar this near the top of your PHP file:

```
// the line below is a bad idea, I apologise to those reading this
require_once('wp-blog-header.php');
```

You may also want to reduce WordPress core load by defining `SHORT_INIT`, though this depends on which functions you are using ( and wether they get loaded when this is defined ).

**But** this is completely the wrong way of going about it. Because its:

- more effort
- wasteful
- slower
- less secure
- likely to incurr a higher maintenance and support cost

Judging from your comment, I would advise you use the REST API instead. Using these APIs will save you time and effort, and it will make things simpler/easier in the long run ( and more secure )

e.g.

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'porton/v1', '/sendemail', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'callback' => 'portons_email_function',
    ) );
} );

function portons_email_function( $request ) {
    // you get the parameters sent from $request:  
    $to = $request['to'];
    $subject = $request['subject'];
    ... etc ...

    // then send your emails

    // and return the result
    return 'Email is sent successfully.';
}
```

and

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url: <?php echo wp_json_encode( esc_url_raw( rest_url( 'porton/v1/sendemail' ) ) ); ?>,
    data: {
        'to':      'example@example.com',
        'subject': 'the subject',
        ...etc...
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
    console.log( data ); // should print email sent successfully int he browser console
});
```

Note that `'permission_callback' => '__return_true',` means everybody can use this endpoint, swap `__return_true` for the name of a function that returns `true` if the user can do this, or `false` if the user cannot to avoid anybody being able to send emails.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but I want to reiterate that I think this is the **wrong approach**, even though it will work.

Comment: Indeed, I agree entirely, so I answered the question and provided a much better alternative instead using the WP AJAX apis (see edited answer)

Comment: Well, strike my previous comment; I left it while you were editing your question. :) +1 for the `wp_jax_` suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

> `mymail.php` is located in the same dir where `style.css` and `functions.php` of the custom theme I am developing is located. It is executed from a .js file when a user clicks a submit button in a form of our theme. `mymail.php` is executed outside of WordPress.

So, basically, I think you've just answered your own question:

> **`mymail.php` is executed outside of WordPress.**

Since the functionality is part of your Theme, there's no reason you can't/shouldn't execute `mymail.php` from *within WordPress*.

Have you considered using the [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function for your form submission?

Comment: It seems you haven't understood my question. My question: How to get WP's functions for a script which is not a part of a WP theme or plugin?

Comment: No, to the contrary: I understand your question completely. I am implying that taking the functionality outside of WordPress is the **wrong approach**, and that you should *instead* execute your form mailer from **within WordPress**.

Answer (score 2):

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE );
require( './wp-load.php' );
```

Use the defined constant to load faster and not all, waht WP have. You will use it on a custom mail function, but its not necessary, that you load all the functions for themes and the themes.

Alternative to `wp-load.php` you can also load the `wp-blog-header.php`, but the wp-load.php is the default file to load WP environment.

Also an hint, set the const
`define( 'SHORTINIT', TRUE );`
to load much more less of files and WP faster. But check it; with this const load WP much smaller and only the important files. (see more information about this on [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47863/load-minimum-wordpress-environment/48079#48079) on other question)