# How to Instantiate wpdb Object in New File

Tags: wpdb

I have a shared hosting account which does not permit me to connect to my databases via mysqli or PDO. However, I can install WordPress and interact with the database via the various built-in forms. Using phpMyAdmin, I am able to create new tables within the WP database. I would like to access the tables I create via my own scripts rather than what WP provides. What wp files do I need to include in order to instantiate a new wpdb object in my script (using the values defined in wp-config.php)?

Comment: Look at posts about loading WordPress environment, like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48107/how-to-load-wp-functions I mean this should answer your question.

Comment: Honestly, seems like a lot of extra work when instead just switching to hosting that allows you to run what you need to run is probably a lot more straightforward.  Or maybe I'm understanding this incorrectly... ...you don't want to USE WordPress and rather are just installing it so you can use WP to connect to the DB?

Comment: That's correct. The reason for doing this rather than simply switching hosts is that I don't want the site to be unavailable for the time it would take to complete the domain transfer and propagation. Last time I did that it took over a week