# Least expensive way to get table prefix in multisite installation

Tags: multisite, database, table, core, optimization

I am writing an api that will have to handle extremely high volumes of calls so, in short, I can not afford to load the WordPress core every call.  I have no problem building the API to use the database directly, and can get all the information I need, save the table prefix, by loading the config file. I have considered a stripped down version of [THIS ANSWER](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45011/27668) but it is still loading way too much and is way too expensive.

There must be a much simpler way.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered to use [WP REST API](http://wp-api.org/)? It is being merged into the core and, with it, you can build headless applications easily.

Comment: it looks like the WP REST API still relies heavily on the core which I can not afford to load.

Comment: Yeah, it still load WordPress core. In fact, it was loading even the admin files in every request (fixed).